# Preg_match getting date out of content

Tags: regex, date, html, preg-match

Hi I'm trying to get date from this content:

```
<div class="article-meta">
  <h1>Kelkraščiu ir prieš eismą</h1>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>Publikuota:</strong>
       2012 spalio 8d.
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Autorius:</strong>

                                    Vardas, Pavardė                            
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>Rubrika:</strong>
      <a href="/ikrauk/naujienos/fotopolicija/" title="Fotopolicija">Fotopolicija</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I need to get this `2012 spalio 8d.` put into variable.

I was trying with `preg_match` but don't now how to complete pattern.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: `preg_match_all("{<li><strong>Publikuota:</strong>(.*?)</li>}six", $data2, $match) problem solved`

Comment: You can answer your own question. This will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/Publikuota:<\/[^>]+>\s*(\d+\s*\w+\s*\w+)/i', $html, $out);
print_r($out[1]);
```